# c++11 zero initialize struct warnings

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, initialization

I'm trying to zero initialize a POD (only `int32_t`, `char[4]`, etc.) struct (it can contain multiple POD structs within it) in three ways:

`struct my_struct s = {};` - this gives me a `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warning,

`struct my_struct s {};` - this gives me a `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warning,

and

`struct my_struct s = my_struct();` this generates no warning

All three instantiations fall under the zero initialization syntax as mentioned here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

Why the warnings in the first two? Which instantiation is guaranteed to initialize my structs with all fields 0 without any garbage values in it?

EDIT - I'm using gcc (g++) 4.8.4 to compile

Comment: On what compiler? I don't get any warnings even with that one specifically enabled. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: GCC 5 no longer warns for these cases.

Comment: `{}` is a empty list while `my_struct()` is a value initialized object.  Two different things.

Comment: @Barry I have gcc 4.8.4

Comment: Then [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61489) is relevant.

Comment: It's a confirmed bug in GCC 4.7 - 4.9 , a leftover from older standard, it shouldn't warn in at least  c++11 compliance mode. @NathanOliver empty list is a type of value initialization, isn't it?

Comment: @Swift Yes but it is a list initialization first.  As the way the standard was written I can see why they warned about it before C++11.

Comment: @NathanOliver they're two different things but in this particular case they should have the same side effect (i.e. zero initializing the struct) right?